# cmd.exe vs. cmd output

Tags: windows, cmd, cygwin

I am running Cygwin on Windows and occasionally I need to call `cmd.exe` from Bash.

However I have noticed that I am getting different results depending on how I call it

```
$ cmd.exe /c 'echo "http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2"'
"http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2"

$ cmd /c 'echo "http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2"'
\"http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2\"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed if you call it like this it is closer to the `cmd.exe` output. Adding a space inside the quotes changes the output.

```
$ cmd /c echo 'http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2 '
"http://asdf.com?a=1&b=2 "
```

More information

```
one or more whitespace characters between the the two quote characters
```

[CMD.exe (Command Shell)](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)